# Horizontally flip an Area in Java

Tags: java, geometry

I have a concave polygon stored as an Area. How would I flip/invert/mirror the polygon about the y-axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Area's [transform](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html#transform(java.awt.geom.AffineTransform)) method.  This takes an AffineTransform object which specifies a single affine transformation.  For the case of flip you can define the following transform

```
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform(new double[] {-1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0});
```

Answer (score 2):

You might try this (I'm assuming your Area object is named polygon):

> `polygon.transform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(0, 1))`

The AffineTransform's getRotateInstance() static method returns a new AffineTransform object with a rotation around the vector <0, 1> (aka the Y-axis).

Comment: @Il-Bhim if you're polygon lies centered on the origin, the rotation about the y-axis will mirror the polygon, not actually move it around the coordinate system. If your polygon isn't on the origin, it will both mirror and move it.